# JavaMail - Quoted printable remove . (dot) on new line

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm using Java Mail to create emails, it's almost working but i'm facing a problem that i don'thave any idea how to resolve it.

The Content-Transfer-Encoding quoted-printable breaks my body in a lot of line with 77 characters each line and the problem happens when the next line starts and the first character is a . (dot).

An example of this:

```
  <table border=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" cellspacing=3D"0" align=3D"center">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td><br /><font color=3D"#666666" face=3D"Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif=
" size=3D"1">Lala n&atilde;o leleler lala lalalaa, <a href=3D"http://t.laiu=
com.ar/TestsTrackings/op.aspx?Osa8Br5zxNpqrv0AtVqBIiGIGG0CPNrUoxbqY7WYcGhP7=
LrlPvlBijtUAlN+b07u4cgghR7erUuf
P9PWGu7YtTkb51txcLYb9+6jzjBtWhf/L8Ai/gdZjrXfmIamviwsffMsjXa8mtnQm8n/XXkWuDw=
8
gW6EpcofAgSMsqpqmqxv85MRVG2vIFuD9v6lFD1H+dMk0RtR/cMhg/zgtjdIym6pig8sSTDT">c=
lalal lala</a>.</font><br /></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

On line i have a link that starts with **http://t.laiu....** and on next line it just removes my dot. When the user receive emails, he gots a link like **t.laiucom.ar...** instead **t.laui.com.ar**.

Anyone have an idea how can i avoid it?

Thank in advance.

Comment: you say you use javamail to _create_ emails, but how do you _send_ them? An SMTP client needs to replace a dot at the beginning of a line [with two dots](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2821#section-4.5.2), SMTP servers remove one dot from the beginning of each line and treat a single dot as end of data. So it's not the encoding that's to be blamed, but the sending client.

Comment: I send them using Windows SMTP that redirects to a MTA. But why the .eml is created without the dot? Javamails is who create the file.

Comment: Yes, but how do you send it to SMTP? javamail should handle lines starting with a `.` correctly when sending a message using `javax.mail.Transport` (by using [SMTPOutputStream](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPOutputStream.java) internally). Do you use some different method to send the message?

Comment: Yes. I create a file .eml and SMTP from windows pickup it from a folder.

Comment: Just to be clear, are the dots there in the generated file? If so, then the pickup program probably expects the file already to be rfc compliant and you must make sure to double each period at the beginning of a line.

Comment: Do you use Message.writeTo to write the message to the .eml file?  And when you view the .eml file with a text editor the dot is missing?  Do you have a simple program that reproduces this problem?  If so, send it to me at javamail_ww@oracle.com.

Comment: @mata in generated file only contains 1 dot

Comment: @BillShannon I'm using MimeMessage.writeTo to write the file. When i check the file it only contains 1 dot. Should it be generated with 2 dots? I'll create a main class and send it to you if it's necessary.

Comment: I've done some tests using Transport.send() and it works so could be a problem when writing a file? Should i manipulate the content to guarantee the 2 dots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you confirmed that you use `Message.writeTo` to create a file, and that the periods are there in that file.

So the problem is not javamail or the quoted printable encoding here.

The pickup service which picks up the file seems to already expect it to be fit for SMTP transport, as per [rfc5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.2) (or rfc2821/rfc821), which means that periods at the beginning of a line must be doubled. `Message.writeTo` won't do that directly, because it does not care about the used transport, it just writes the message to a stream.

Usually, when sent to SMTP through `javax.mail.Transport` javamail handles this by wrapping the output stream in a [SMTPOutputStream](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/mail/src/main/java/com/sun/mail/smtp/SMTPOutputStream.java), so everything works fine. But by using `Message.writeTo` directly, you're operating on a lower level and need to deal with correctly formatting the output so it is accepted by the pickup service yourself.

That means you need to replace dots at the beginning of a line with two dots yourself. To do so you could use the SMTPOutputStream wrapper class mentioned above (but it's not public/documented API), or write your own stream wrapper which does the same. Or any other way to modify the generated data you like...